# PHP error get_result() undefined method

Tags: php

i'm new on the forum so i'll try my best.
I have an error with the PHP code because my server host doesn't support mysqlnd Driver. I know that i have to use bind_result(); but i have no idea how to do (i'm learning).

Please help me! Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
/**
 * Storing new user
 * returns user details
 */
public function storeUser($name, $email, $password) {
    $uuid = uniqid('', true);
    $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
    $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
    $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, NOW())");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $uuid, $name, $email, $encrypted_password, $salt);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();

    // check for successful store
    if ($result) {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        // Error here
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        return $user;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Get user by email and password
 */
public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        // Error here
        $user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        $stmt->close();

        // verifying user password
        $salt = $user['salt'];
        $encrypted_password = $user['encrypted_password'];
        $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
        // check for password equality
        if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
            // user authentication details are correct
            return $user;
        }
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: `$stmt->execute();$user = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();` change it to `$result = $stmt->execute();$user = $result->get_result()->fetch_assoc();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace the `$stmt` with `$result` after `Error here`

```
$result = $stmt->execute(); 
// Error here     $user=$result->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
```

Comment: This is the Log.d "Call to a member function get_result() on a non-object"...
Before "Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()"...
Any idea?